# Booking system weekly

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to setup a database/table in PHP using MySQL.
I have 50 kennels that are needing to be booked out.

What I don't know how to do is setup a calendar that shows weekly bookings?

How do I create a calendar using PHP to pull out a week at a time with all 50 kennels listed on the left hand side with the dates displayed at the top ?

```
           Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday
 Kennel1   Bobby   Bobby   Bobby     Bobby    Free    Free    Free
 Kennel2   Free    Free    Free      Teddy    Teddy   Teddy   Teddy
 Kennel3   Free    Free    Free      Free     Free    Free    Free
```

Like the above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround using PHP alone:

```
$ddate = "2016-03-10";//Given the date
$date = new DateTime($ddate);
$week_number = $date->format("W");//Find the week number
$year = $date->format("Y");//Find the year
echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Kennels</th>';
for($day=1; $day<=7; $day++){
    echo '<th>'.date('D', strtotime($year."W".$week_number.$day))."</th>";
}
echo '</tr>';
```

The number of kennel rows and each Day rows must match:

```
foreach($kennels as $kennel){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td></td>';//50 Kennel rows   
    echo '</tr>';
}
foreach($bobyfree as $bf){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td></td>';//Bobby/Free must be output based on Day using custom function
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```